# Storing result in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with storing results in a matrix. a is my time series with a certain rate. Now I would like to have that rate quarterly, so I did the following:

```
a = [1 4.2; 2 3.9; 3 3.7; 4 3.9; 5 4.1; 6 4.3; 7 4.2; 8 4.1; 9 4.4; 10 4.5; 11 5.1; 12 5.2;13 5.8]

for K = 1:3:10;
    result(K, 1) = a(K+3, 2)-a(K, 2)
end
```

Unfortunately, the result vector is now a 10x1 vector, but actually I would like it to be a 4x1 vector only with the 4 quarterly values. For the given example my desired output would be [-0.3 0.3 0.3 1.3].

Anyone an idea how to do so? Any help appreciated!

Comment: The loop variable `K` will have the values `1 4 7 10`. Thus, you will assign a value to `result(10,1)` and the size of `result` will be `10x1` (not 13, after your edit). Let `K` run from `1:4` and compute the index for accessing `a` accordingly.

Comment: @HansHirse Thats exactly what I wanted, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [Patrick Happel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604664/storing-result-in-a-matrix#comment103520718_58604664), in your example, `K` have will values from `[1 4 7 10]`. By accessing `result(K, 1)` for `K = 10`, your `result` array "automatically" will have a size of `10x1`.

To prevent that, you can "precalculate" the indices from `K` and access the corresponding elements in `a` directly without using any loop.

Here are the codes next to each other:

```matlab
% Input
a = [1 4.2; 2 3.9; 3 3.7; 4 3.9; 5 4.1; 6 4.3; 7 4.2; 8 4.1; 9 4.4; 10 4.5; 11 5.1; 12 5.2;13 5.8]

% Using loop
for K = 1:3:10;
    result(K, 1) = a(K+3, 2)-a(K, 2);
end
result

% Using precalculated indices
K = 1:3:10;
result = a(K+3, 2)-a(K, 2)
```

And, the outputs:

```
a =
    1.0000    4.2000
    2.0000    3.9000
    3.0000    3.7000
    4.0000    3.9000
    5.0000    4.1000
    6.0000    4.3000
    7.0000    4.2000
    8.0000    4.1000
    9.0000    4.4000
   10.0000    4.5000
   11.0000    5.1000
   12.0000    5.2000
   13.0000    5.8000

result =
  -0.30000
   0.00000
   0.00000
   0.30000
   0.00000
   0.00000
   0.30000
   0.00000
   0.00000
   1.30000

result =
  -0.30000
   0.30000
   0.30000
   1.30000
```

Hope that helps!